# How to use current date (yyyy-mm-dd) as part of a Select-String -Pattern with Get_Content command

Tags: powershell

I have an excel workbook with VBA code that executes a Powershell command-line script to extract information from a log file based on a pattern check.

The problem I'm having is that there are multiple lines with matching text and the only differentiator is the date.

I'm looking for a way to add the current date, in the format of yyyy-mm-dd, as a matching criteria.

The current command line code is:

```
Get-Content '\\logging\server.log' | Select-String -Pattern "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}.*finished executing" -CaseSensitive
```

This code returns the expected result set of 4 lines:

```
139907928364800 [488] 2019-09-02 Process "Metadata Control":  finished executing.
139856228501248 [4311] 2019-09-03 Process "Metadata Control":  finished executing.
139855148627712 [8289] 2019-09-04 Process "Metadata Control":  finished executing.
139854016616192 [11892] 2019-09-05 Process "Metadata Control":  finished executing.
```

However, I only want the last line, where the date equals 2019-09-05 (current date), to be returned.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: add "| select-object -last 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet also has a `-Path` parameter, so there is no need to use `Get-Content` here:

```
(Select-String -Path '\\logging\server.log' -Pattern "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}.*finished executing" -CaseSensitive | Select-Object -Last 1).Line
```

Returns

> ```
> 139854016616192 [11892] 2019-09-05 Process "Metadata Control":  finished executing.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
$today = (get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$filename = "C:\temp\test.txt"
$Search = Select-String -Path $filename -Pattern $today | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LineNumber'
foreach ($single_Number in $Search) {
    (Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt")[$single_Number - 1]
}
```

This outputs the Lines which contain the current Date, or any other Day when you add days for example yesterday:
`$today = (get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: if you DO NOT strip out the other properties from the `Select-String`, you won't need to re-read the file. the line will be in the props of the `matchinfo` object that `Select-String` returns. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thats right, but then you _only_ get the matched pattern. In this case the output is the matched Date

Comment: that is not what i see. the returned object holds the line number [that you got from that object], the line of text, and some more stuff. try sending the output of  the `Select-String` to `| Select-Object -Property *` and you will see several props - LineNumber, Line, Patern, and several others.

Answer (score 0):

If the line you want is -always- last, you could just select the last line.

```
Get-Content '\\logging\server.log' |
    Select-String -Pattern "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}.*finished executing" -CaseSensitive |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

This could help if the last entry was not made today. For example, the last entry was on Friday, but today is Monday.